# how to make your website logo to be responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I've set the max-width of my logo to 112 and it's perfect for the desktop, as for the mobile version it's not. here's the link of my website http://mediagrafter.com/logistics/#?

I've tried to decrease the margin-left but it's not being adjusted in the mobile version (responsive).

```
<pre>
    <img src="wp-content/uploads/2018/09/logo.png" alt="" style="
        max-width: 112%;
    ">
</pre>
```

I want the logo to be adjusted in the mobile view (responsive), but it displays half of the logo.

Comment: Use less than or equal value to 100, for width...like this: `<img src="..." width="100%"/>`

Comment: Code formatting, minor improvements to question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try this:

```
<pre>
    <img src="wp-content/uploads/2018/09/logo.png" alt="" style="
        device-width;
    ">
</pre>
```

Or add in the `<head>` section of your document specific the meta  tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also if it is not working add to the style sheet css the following:

```
@-ms-viewport{ width: device-width; }
```

read this  for more information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can set width to 100%, and then set the *object-fit* property to *contain*

Other idea is to set

```
{ width: 100%, height: auto; }
```